# Failed to load root config module: Error parsing /home/milenko/brikman/main.tf: At 41:1: heredoc not terminated

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to run terraform.This is my main.tf

```
provider "aws" { region = "eu-central-1"}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami = "ami-df8403b0"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.instance.id}"]

user_data = <<-EOF
#!/bin/bash
  echo "Hello, World" > index.html
  nohup busybox httpd -f -p "${var.server_port}" &
EOF

tags {
  Name = "terraform-example"
}

}

variable "server_port" {
  description = "The port the server will use for HTTP requests"
  default = 8080
}


resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {
 name = "terraform-example-instance"
 ingress {
   from_port = "${var.server_port}"
   to_port = "${var.server_port}"
   protocol = "tcp"
   cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
        }
 }
```

If I want to check dependancy graph,this is what I got

Failed to load root config module: Error parsing /home/milenko/brikman/main.tf: At 41:1: heredoc not terminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HCL parser is whitespace sensitive, so make sure there is no tabs in the mix. Also make sure to have a linebreak between the EOF and the tags statement.

```
user_data = <<-EOF
        #!/bin/bash
        echo "Hello, World" > index.html
        nohup busybox httpd -f -p "${var.server_port}" &
        EOF

 tags {
   ...
```